# Angular2 routerLink params

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

My angular2 app has this routes configuration

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: 'SignIn', component: LoginComponent },
{
    path: 'Home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [LoggedInGuard]
    , children: [
        { path: 'ViewUserDetails/:pageTitle', component: ViewUserDetailsComponent },
    ]
}];
```

I wanted to use the pageTitle parameter in my component so I passed it in the routerLink this way

```
<a [routerLink]="['/Home/ViewUserDetails',{pageTitle:'View Channel User'}]">View Channel User</a>
```

But I get this error

> core.umd.js:3257 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match
>   any routes. URL Segment:
>   'Home/ViewUserDetails;pageTitle=View%20Channel%20User'

The angular documentation used this to pass parameters I don't understand why it produces this form of the link instead of

> /Home/ViewUserDetails/View%20Channel%20User

Comment: Try `<a [routerLink]="['/Home/ViewUserDetails','View Channel User']">View Channel User</a>`

Comment: thanks alot @HarryNinh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular 2 router does work on URL fragment base. It navigates between route based on URL `pattern`.

You should be having just array of expression(here its string).

```
<a [routerLink]="['/Home/ViewUserDetails','View Channel User']">View Channel User</a>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked .but i don't understand what does it mean to use the object here that way {pageTitle:'View Channel User'}

Comment: @YassmeenMahmoud May I know what you don't understand, I'd love to explain it.

Comment: I don't know when to use this `<a [routerLink]="['/crisis-center', { foo: 'foo' }]">Crisis Center</a>` that was mentioned in the example of the angular documentation [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#link-parameters-array)

Comment: @YassmeenMahmoud you should do that only when you wanted to pass optional parameter, which haven't mentioned in route